# System.InvalidOperationException: 'No 'id' member found on type

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, azure-mobile-services

I'm getting this error only on release build of xamarin forms IOS.

**App.xaml.cs**

```
 public partial class App : Application
    {
        public static MobileServiceClient MobileService = new MobileServiceClient(B2CConstants.ApplicationURL, new HttpClientHandler());
        public static BaseViewModel BaseViewModel = new BaseViewModel();

        public static ShapeTypeViewModel ShapeTypeViewModel = new ShapeTypeViewModel();
        public static HoleDataViewModel HoleMapViewModel = new HoleDataViewModel();
        public static PlayersViewModel PlayersViewModel = new PlayersViewModel();
        public static RoundsViewModel RoundsViewModel = new RoundsViewModel();
        public static ScoresViewModel ScoresViewModel = new ScoresViewModel();
        public static TeeTimesViewModel TeeTimesViewModel = new TeeTimesViewModel();
        public static TournamentViewModel TournamentSamplesViewModel = new TournamentViewModel();

        public static ShapesViewModel ShapeViewModel = new ShapesViewModel();

        public static MyTournamentsViewModel MyTournamentsViewModel = new MyTournamentsViewModel(); 
        public static MyTournamentCoursesViewModel MyTournamentCoursesViewModel = new MyTournamentCoursesViewModel();
        public static MyTournamentPlayersViewModel MyTournamentPlayersViewModel = new MyTournamentPlayersViewModel();
        public static MyTournamentLeaderboardViewModel MyTournamentLeaderboardViewModel = new MyTournamentLeaderboardViewModel();
        public static MyTournamentRoundsViewModel MyTournamentRoundsViewModel = new MyTournamentRoundsViewModel();
        public static MyTournamentScoresViewModel MyTournamentScoresViewModel = new MyTournamentScoresViewModel();
        public static MyTournamentYardagesViewModel MyTournamentYardagesViewModel = new MyTournamentYardagesViewModel();
```

Whatever viewmodel is called first (that calls  azure mobile services)- causes the error.

**ShapesViewModel.cs**

```
   public class ShapesViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public MobileServiceCollection<GeoPosShapes, GeoPosShapes> shapeItems;
        public IMobileServiceSyncTable<AzureShapes> ShapesTable = App.MobileService.GetSyncTable<AzureShapes>(); // offline sync
```

**The error occurs on calling** 
GetSyncTable(Tablename).

**Shapes.cs**

```
namespace RangeFinder.Models
{
    public class AzureShapes
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public int shapetypeid { get; set; }
        public string courseid { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "wkt")]
        public string WKT { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "hole")]
        public int Hole { get; set; }
    }

    public class GeoPosShapes
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public int shapetypeid { get; set; }
        public string courseid { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "hole")]
        public int Hole { get; set; }

        public List<Position> PolyGeoPos { get; set; }
        //public MapElement mapElement { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The error message is:

*The thread 0x6 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
2020-06-18 22:44:36.650 RangeFinder.iOS[571:98215] System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'RangeFinder.App' threw an exception. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: No 'id' member found on type 'RangeFinder.Models.ShapeTypes'.
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceContractResolver.DetermineIdProperty (System.Type type, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] properties) [0x00070] in :0 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceContractResolver.CreatePropertiesInner (System.Type type, Newtonsoft.Json.MemberSerialization memberSerialization) [0x00075] in :0 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceContractResolver.CreateProperties (System.Type type, Newtonsoft.Json.MemberSerialization memberSerialization) [0x0004f] in :0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateObjectContract (System.Type objectType) [0x0003a] 
in <2073514815234917a5e8f91b0b239405>:0 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceContractResolver.CreateObjectContract (System.Type objectType) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateContract (System.Type objectType) [0x0010f] in <2073514815234917a5e8f91b0b239405>:0 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceContractResolver.ResolveTableName (System.Type type) [0x000ea] in :0 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient.GetSyncTable[T] () [0x0000b] in :0 
  at RangeFinder.ViewModels.ShapeTypeViewModel..ctor () [0x00000] in C:\Users\Karl\Source\Repos\RangeFinder\RangeFinder.standard\ViewModels\ShapeTypeViewModel.cs:13 
  at RangeFinder.App..cctor () [0x00027] in C:\Users\Karl\Source\Repos\RangeFinder\RangeFinder.standard\Views\App.xaml.cs:36 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at RangeFinder.iOS.AppDelegate
.FinishedLaunching (UIKit.UIApplication app, Foundation.NSDictionary options) [0x00093] in <92430b17376a435287b491877f96ca89>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.18.2.1/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:86 
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0000e] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.18.2.1/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:65 
  at RangeFinder.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <92430b17376a435287b491877f96ca89>:0 
**System.TypeInitializationException:** 'Loading...'*

Any help would be appreciated - as this is the last step before getting app published on IOS AppStore

Comment: there are a number of hits related to that error message on google

Comment: I appreciate that - but they have all been examined thoroughly but without solving my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have not given is all the types involved.  See:

```
No 'id' member found on type 'RangeFinder.Models.ShapeTypes'.
```

You explicitly want to look at `RangeFinder.Models.ShapeTypes` type.  There is no id field on that type.